# Transparent firewall can't access http and https

Tags: firewall, iptables

iptables -L outputs:

```
[root@itsys ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state    RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:bootpc dpt:bootps 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PHYSDEV match --physdev-in eth0 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.16.16.113        anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.16.16.113        anywhere            tcp dpt:https 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

here is the Linux transparent bridge setting: eth0 connects to a switch and eth1 connects to a test machine(172.16.16.113). I can't access http web site by site on the test machine but can access the same site by ip address. the https site can't be accessed either

Comment: do you add an output with masquerade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add dns forward then ok
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 172.16.16.0/24 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT